# jquery validation using class attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have multiple text fields in my form which should contain only 5 alphabets and required fields. I am using jQuery Validation for this using class attribute.

Sample code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <cfsavecontent variable="headerJS">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validateCurrency.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                alert("function");

                jQuery.validator.addMethod("APUnit", function(value, element) {
                    return this.optional(element) || /^[A_Za-z]{5}$/i.test(value);
                }, " ");

                jQuery.validator.addMethod("cRequired", jQuery.validator.methods.required, "Customer name required");       
                jQuery.validator.addClassRules("APunit1",{APUnit: true, cRequired: true});          
            }); 
        </script>

        <style>
            label.error {
                color: red;
                font-style: italic;
                background: transparent url(images/unchecked.gif) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
                padding-left:20px;
                margin-left:10px;
            }
            input.error { border: 1px dotted red; }
            .border td {
                border-left: 1px solid black;
                border-right: 1px solid black;
                border-top: 1px solid black;
                border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            }
            .border th{
                border-left: 1px solid black;
                border-right: 1px solid black;
                border-top: 1px solid black;
                border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </cfsavecontent>

    <cfhtmlhead text="#headerJS#">
    <body>
        <cfform name="eForm" method="POST">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name" class="APUnit1">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </cfform>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I am not getting any error message when I gave invalid input. Validation is  working. I couldn't find the bug in it. Please help me to get through this.

Comment: `APUnit` ? `APUnit1` ? `APunit1` ? Are you not messing with these terms?

Comment: You forgot to initialize the plugin with the `.validate()` method.  Please also be more careful when tagging.  jQuery Validation Engine is not jQuery Validate plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter how you create and/or declare your rules, you still must attach the `.validate()` method to your form in order to initialize the plugin.

```
$(function() {

    $('form[name="eForm"]').validate();

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("APUnit", function(value, element) { ....
    ....
```

You also misspelled `APunit1` here...

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="APUnit1">
```

It's spelled as `APunit1` here...

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules("APunit1" ....
```

Initialize the plugin and fix the spelling error:

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/pcgb4moj/**